# How to Concat String in SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, string-concatenation

I have declared two variables in RAW sql

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max), @str1 nvarchar (max);

SET @str = "  AND (c.BondSales_Confirmed <> -1)";

SET @str1 = "  AND (c.BondSales_IssueType = 'REGULAR')";
```

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT * From t_BondSales Where (BondSales_cType <> 'Institute') " + str1 + str  "
```

Here I get the following error:

> Error: SQL Problems: Incorrect Syntax near  "+ str1 + str"

Can any one  Please help me with the proper syntax about how to concat String in where clause?

Comment: It was showing you error just because you left "@" symbol before your variable names in the select query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
       @str NVARCHAR(MAX)
     , @str1 NVARCHAR (MAX);

SELECT 
       @str = ' AND c.BondSales_Confirmed != -1'
     , @str1 = ' AND c.BondSales_IssueType = ''REGULAR''';

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = '
SELECT * 
FROM t_BondSales 
WHERE BondSales_cType != ''Institute'''
     + @str 
     + @str1

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Can you suggest me another last thing, which is: Is this String concatenation is supported in Jasper (iReport)? @Devart

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know exactly about that. Possibly - yes.

Answer (score 20):

very easy!! in mysql use CONCAT() function:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_person WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) = 'Walter White';
```

but this does **not** work in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_person WHERE first_name+' '+last_name = 'Walter White';
```

Comment: The `CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) = ''` one works with JPA TypedQuery too. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The question is about MS SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Passing column names along with values is subject to SQL Injection. Make sure to read this post www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

So I would suggest you to change the code like this

```
declare @BondSales_Confirmed int
declare @BondSales_IssueType varchar(100)

SELECT * From t_BondSales Where (BondSales_cType <> 'Institute')
AND (c.BondSales_Confirmed <> @BondSales_Confirmed  or @BondSales_Confirmed is null)
AND (c.BondSales_IssueType = @BondSales_IssueType or @BondSales_IssueType is null)
```

Just pass null value if you do not want to apply a condition to the columns BondSales_Confirmed and BondSales_IssueType

Comment: This doesn't serve my purpose actually. Thanks anyway @Madhivanan